# Помогите реализовать слайдер без испрользования JavaScript

Tags: html, css

Помогите реализовать слайдер, без использования JavaScript.

1. С помощью radio button нужно переключать блоки, в каждом блоке по 4 фото, всего их 4.
   У меня это получилось, но только с помощью JavaScript.**Помогите переписать используя только html,css**

Необязательно чтобы radio button были в блоках(как на фото), они могут быть сверху или снизу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const sliderWrapper = document.querySelector('.slider-wrapper');
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-button');

radioButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const translateValue = -index * 100;
    sliderWrapper.style.transform = `translateX(${translateValue}%)`;
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slide {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.slide img {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider-radio {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.radio-button {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-button:checked {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider" checked>
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: с чем именно возникли проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать псевдокласс [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), то изменения будут минимальны:

```css
.slider-container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-radio {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.radio-button {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-button:checked {
  background-color: black;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slider-radio:has(.radio-button[value="1"]:checked)+.slider-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slider-radio:has(.radio-button[value="2"]:checked)+.slider-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slider-radio:has(.radio-button[value="3"]:checked)+.slider-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.slider-radio:has(.radio-button[value="4"]:checked)+.slider-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}

.slide {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.slide img {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">

  <div class="slider-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider" value="2">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider" value="3">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="slider" value="4">
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo1.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo2.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo3.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/100x200?text=photo4.jpg" alt="photo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```